# Embedding data into mongo documents as a many to many but stuck on how

Tags: python, mongodb

*Sorry for the vague title had trouble trying to word it.*

Essentially I'm re-working a Discord bot and I'm at the ranking system for it. I'm using Pymongo *(that' the reason for the python tag)*.

I have `Users` and `Guilds` collections and I'm wondering how I'd establish ranks for each user per guild. I need to be able to get the highest level user(s) globally (across all guilds) and highest user(s) for a particular guild by `guild_id` as well as access users rank by their `user_id`. I also have more data than just ranks to store in each member field but the ranking data is just the start.

**Currently,**

the way I have been storing the data in its own collection called `Members` but this feels wrong/inefficient as they are small documents and there's repeated data in this case; kind of feels like an sql many to many relationship.

**`Memebers`**

```
{
    user_id: int32,
    guild_id: int32,
    background: string,
    level: int32,
    points: int32
}
```

---

Should I embed the ranking data into Guilds as a document and the keys are the `user_id`?

```
{
    "_id" : int32,
    users : {
        1 : {
            background: string,
            level: int32,
            points: int32,
        },
        ...
    }
}
```

Or do I make `members` field an array?

```
{
    "_id" : int32,
    users : [
        {
            user_id: 1,
            background: string,
            level: int32,
            points: int32,
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

The other possible solution I've thought of is embedding membership info into each user but don't think that would make much sense compared to the later.

Currently all I need to do to get the top 10 in a server is:

```
members.find({_id:guild_id}).sort([('level', -1), ('points', -1)].limit(10)
```

And for top 10 overall just omit the filter.

How would I go about this if it was embedded? I'd assume an aggregation?